# UIBarStyleBlack causes navigationBar not to show shadow in popover

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I'm showing a `UINavigationController` hierarchy in `UIPopoverController`. When I set the `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlack`, the shadow in the navigation bar is not shown.Does anybody know why it can be?

Thanks a lot!